# Getting an "The recipient of this payment is Unregistered" error when trying to use PayPal "Buy Now" button

Tags: c#, asp.net, paypal

I'm trying to get my Buy Now button in PayPal Sandbox to work. However when I make a purchase using it, it does not show up on my business transaction overview. And in the personal account, it shows as "Unclaimed" and "The recipient of this payment is Unregistered". Here is the ASP.NET code I'm using for the button:

```
<form action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_top">
        <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick" />
        <input type="hidden" name="notify_url" value="censored" />
        <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Aktivt kontigent" />
        <input type="hidden" name="item_number" value="1" />
        <input type="hidden" name="amount" value="240" />
        <input type="hidden" name="tax_rate" value="25" />
        <input type="hidden" name="undefined_quantity" value="0" />
        <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD" />
        <input type="hidden" name="handling" value="5" />
        <input type="hidden" name="business" value="censored" />
        <asp:ImageButton ID="btnPayNow" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/images/btn_buynowCC_LG.gif" PostBackUrl="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr"/>
</form>
```

I know I'm using the right business ID, because my Business name appears on the checkout page on PayPal. And the IPN is also working, I can see that on my server. However the transaction does not appear on seller account, and the personal account is having this weird status. Does anyone know how to fix this please?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: It's been some time since I've done Paypal - are you using your `sandbox` id when doing `sandbox` testing? Also, this seems more a Paypal matter than anything to do with ASP.Net....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with this was my e-mail was not veryfied. It worked after that.